# What are differences between same ROM for different devices?

Tags: android, operating-system, porting, cyanogenmod, hal

### **For example, can anybody give some concrete examples of differences between Cyanogen Mod 10 for Samsung i9100g and CM 10 for i9100?**

As far as I know, they have different hardware and that's why their drivers are different, as a result their HAL are very different from the other. However, I'd like to have an example contains -maybe- several lines of code.

I am aware that there are many many people who wants to get into Android porting/development and does not know how to start what to modify/change, I am one of those. I think the answer of this question will be beneficial for those.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest is going to be the kernel and the RIL (radio interface layer).

Different devices have different hardware.  Different hardware needs different drivers.  If you have two similar devices often little modification needs to be made to run one OS on a sibling device.  However, even hardware that *looks* the same externally can have drastically different internals.

If you want to get into platform development, follow some of the people who do it and look through what they're doing.  [jt1134](https://github.com/jt1134) does a lot of the kernel and platform dev for the Samsung devices.  The [CyanogenMod org](https://github.com/CyanogenMod) has a lot of code worth looking at too and the team even has [a wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Building_from_source) that goes into some of the finer details about building from source.

You should also sit around in the Android development IRC rooms on the Freenode and Mod-a-droid servers.  You can ask questions but don't always expect to get an answer.  You can even try PMing jt1134 on freenode (if he still hangs out there), he's pretty responsive if you can convince him you know what you're doing << as in read all the publicly available documentation first.

Here is an outline of the process you need to follow.

Milestones:

0.5.  Setup a development environment http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

1. Download the [kernel sources from Samsung](http://opensource.samsung.com/).
2. Compile the Linux kernel.
3. Wade through all the developer docs at [source.android.com](http://source.android.com/index.html)
4. Download the Android platform sources from [googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/).
5. Make any modifications required for your device (for example: you may need specific vendor files (drivers) for your device, you might need some custom init scripts, etc.).
6. Compile the android platform <-- this takes a long time

After this, you should have a OTA flashable copy of the Android Open Source Project that you can test on your device.  This process took me about a month to research and get down, it's not a trivial endeavor, I wish you luck.